# Phalcon PHP - Converting from HEX strings to Binary(16) and back during model save/read/hydration

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon PHP 3.0.4 and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Given this MySQL MariaDB table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
    `Id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    INDEX `Email` (`Email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

How would I achieve the following (using a Phalcon PHP preferred approach):

1. Take a regular HEX string either with or without dashes (example '15E077BCFD8511E683A600FF8A8C8699') in PHP and convert it to Binary(16) just before Phalcon saves the 'Id' property to the 'Id' column?
2. Take the value of the 'Id' column and convert it back to a HEX string from Binary(16) so the result would be a Hex string either with or without dashes?

I followed this article for storing GUIDs as Primary keys in MariaDB and then I realized that the Hex/Binary conversion really needs to happen in PHP so Phalcon won't store binary data in it's model objects in memory.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/guiduuid-performance/

At the end of the day this 'Id' column value is passed around in the HTTP request and responses to be used in other systems. Therefore passing around binary GUIDs is not going to work for me, hence why I need to convert it between strings and binary just before it enters and leaves the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out.

Using PHP I generate a GUID and convert it to binary from hex using PHP's `hex2bin()` function.

Last night this appeared to not be working because I was getting an error in my action method `Unexpected 'o'` and I thought this error was produced by the binary data. It appears that error was produced because I was calling `$this->response->setJsonContent()` without a parameter.

The final working PHP code is below:

```
function getGUID(){
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
    $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
    $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
        .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
        .substr($charid,20,12);
    return $uuid;
}

$guid = getGUID();
var_dump($guid);
$player2 = new Players([
    "Id" => hex2bin(str_replace('-', '', $guid)),
    "Email" => "phalcon@gmail.com"
]);
var_dump($player2->save());
var_dump(bin2hex($player2->getId()));
```

The result of executing the code above is as expected:

```
string(36) "C03F5B38-FF32-8D32-EC42-797A764E8684"
bool(true)
string(32) "c03f5b38ff328d32ec42797a764e8684"
```

The GUID value is stored in MariaDB correctly, too.

[image]